# Merge based on joined attribute in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I have a single layer of polygons (drawn around every zip code). I have a CSV file with territory numbers and the zip codes in each territory. I joined these and was able to color each territory (multiple zip codes) instead of each individual zipcode. What I'd like to do now is get rid of the zip code boundaries to only have the territory boundaries, but I can't figure out how to do this.

Comment: The operation you're looking for is called a Dissolve. I can't recall of the top of my head if it works on joined data (as in you may have to save the join out to a new file first, then dissolve) but I think it should.

Comment: @ChrisW I saw dissolve, but it didn't have the field that I needed to dissolve on listed. Your suggestion to save out the join first and then dissolve was the missing link. Thanks! Feel free to post as an answer so I can accept.

Comment: Happy to help. Since this question is pretty much a duplicate of the other one (and the exact issue you were having is covered there), it's been closed and doesn't accept new answers. That way we keep information consolidated and duplication on the site to a minimum. You can always upvote the question/answer there since the information helps solve your problem and your votes would help indicate that information is useful to others.